# Arquitecthure of the project

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee

I want to create a software about sports and nutrition and I am trying to create a multi-module project with multiples environments.

First , I would like to create six modules ,nutrition , sports , healthy , this modules has a backend and frontend that they consume a restful webservice.

So , the structure of the project I am thinking is the following (This modules will be more subdmodules)

-**back-sports
-back-nutrition
-back-health
-front-sports
-front-nutrition
-front-health
-authentication
-authorization
-rest-api**

I am not sure how to consume the rest api , but I am sure that I will be use JavaScript(This is the next step to think)

The part of the rest api will be : Jersey , Spring/POJO , JPA/Hibernate.

Database : MySQL

What is better ? Separte the module rest-api in another project or not.

Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have rest-api as separate module, you just "inject" services from bussines modules, so rest api module will just expose those services to the rest transport layer.
Btw if you use spring boot you have security already in.